# Changing Original Message headers (from Unit of Work). Is it safe / a good practise?

Tags: apache-camel

I need to use original message in my onException clause but I also need some data that has been processed just after the start of the camel context.

In order to achieve that, I use the next instruction in a processor:

exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage().setHeader("my_header", "value");

I have read the documentation and seems safe to access to the headers that way and it actually works (i do have the headers needed in the onException clause).

Still, since the unit of work implies a transaction group i am afraid of a context where i should never use it.

Is it safe to use it?

Thanks,